# Add search for app that hold data in XML file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that hold its data in XML file. That file contain elements and sub-elements, about 300 + entities. Please, take a look at part of that file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <Kremlin>Кремль и Красная площадь<place>
            <name>Московский кремль</name>
            <description>Моско́вский Кре́мль — древнейшая часть Москвы, главный общественно-политический, духовно-религиозный и историко-художественный комплекс города, официальная резиденция Президента Российской Федерации. Расположен на высоком левом берегу Москвы-реки — Боровицком холме, при впадении в неё р. Неглинной. В плане Кремль — неправильный треугольник площадью 27,5 га. Южная стена обращена к Москве-реке, северо-западная — к Александровскому саду, восточная — к Красной площади. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Московский_Кремль</description>
            <webpage>http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Московский_Кремль</webpage>
            <latitude>55.75212</latitude>
            <longitude>37.617665</longitude>
            <imageCell>https://dl.dropbox.com/s/0o6h7bmn1muj7oz/MKCell.jpg</imageCell>
            <imageFirst>https://dl.dropbox.com/s/9bsvnfccxy0s8rn/MK1.jpg</imageFirst>
            <imageSecond>https://dl.dropbox.com/s/jq5gv1a58qg4llx/MK2.jpeg</imageSecond>
            <imageThird>https://dl.dropbox.com/s/5vvt4k64oj47f42/MK3.jpg</imageThird>
            <imageFourth>https://dl.dropbox.com/s/jruja8o4iwf8r55/MK4.jpg</imageFourth>
        </place>
        <place>
            <name>Спасская башня</name>
            <description>Спа́сская башня (ранее — Фроло́вская башня) — выходящая на Красную площадь одна из 20 башен Московского Кремля. В башне расположены главные ворота Кремля — Спасские, в шатре башни установлены знаменитые часы — куранты.</description>
            <webpage>http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Спасская_башня</webpage>
            <latitude>55.752696</latitude>
            <longitude>37.621672</longitude>
            <imageCell>https://dl.dropbox.com/s/sjpqthepnqxfr0r/SBCell.jpg</imageCell>
            <imageFirst>https://dl.dropbox.com/s/fch0kvr8ltzx41i/SB1.jpg</imageFirst>
            <imageSecond>https://dl.dropbox.com/s/o6tiayev00z3uen/SB2.jpg</imageSecond>
            <imageThird>https://dl.dropbox.com/s/iy7cuw98fxq3cda/SB3.jpg</imageThird>
            <imageFourth>https://dl.dropbox.com/s/luephoe2e03njtu/SB4.jpg</imageFourth>
        </place>
```

What i want is, to implement a search bar. When user start typing text, entity with that name comes up. My problem in following - I'm not sure how to achieve this, when i found "Кремль" for example, i need to somehow pass information about sub-elements. App should show a correct image for that entity, description and other, which is stored in sub-elements of XML file. Maybe, there is a way to do this with NSDictionary?

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Convert the XML to JSON if it is something you have stored in your app bundle. Then use `NSJSONSerialization` to get an NSArray/NSDictionary.

Answer (score 1):

See , this can be done easily but in few steps.
**First** - Parse the data properly and create array of dictionaries .

**Second** - You should use a local database like sqlite and save all the images in Blob datatype (blob datatype can save your image in form of NS data). Here is the trick part that you have to create this table with 2 columns, one name and other with image data. i.e you store all image data in front of respective image name and extract from db whenever requires.

**Third** **-Implement search bar.**Now as your entire data has already been parsed and stored in array (or dictionary) . For eg suppose user types in search bar "krem" , apply code to search for key kremlin and use this kremlin key to search in your parsed data.Find suitable url name from dictionary and extract image from DB with this url name (name was our field in db).

You can easily achieve this but its a lot of work to be done.. Try this..